# Grid Layout+Card Doesnt show images

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

please help,

I am making a webview app for my college project, each grid items on click will launch separate webviews.
but I am stuck in the grid layout itself.
I tried many solutions but couldn't figure out the issue.. 
[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKD8L.png)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ikkantekada"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
```

}

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="313dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logopng" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="സ്വാഗതം, നിങ്ങൾക്കിഷ്ടമുള്ളവ തിരഞ്ഞെടുക്കൂ "
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SignOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
            android:text="Sign Out"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="14dp">

        <!-- ROW 1  -->
        <!-- COLUMN 1  -->



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/bag"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- COLUMN 2  -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/bag"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text2"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <!-- ROW 2  -->
        <!-- COLUMN 1  -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/news"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text3"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- COLUMN 2  -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/cooking.png"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text4"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- ROW 3  -->
        <!-- COLUMN 1  -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/bag"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- COLUMN 2  -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/cake"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Text2"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: you are using  androidx dependency but using support library card view change that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gradle file you have imported `CardView` dependency for `androidx`, but in your `XML` file you are using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Change it to `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and give it a try.